# Insert new data instead of copying entire row Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've a column of data (dates) in one sheet which is transposed as row to another sheet. Each date has column of data under it in the destination sheet.

I want to move only new data of source sheet inserted as blank column to destination sheet without affecting existing data. I've added "desired result" tab with destination sheet, in case my query is confusing.

Kindly help

[Source sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19ZJK4JMYffFW57FHRz0NsvwRA72wfdI2TVdOjsB6g7o/edit?usp=sharing)

[Destination sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pAmwrI8JS22fErYqKSpIWhlI8PTAYzh_2E2iJnu4qXE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: You've forgotten to add what you've done so far, and what is the problem you have.

Comment: You can probably use Class Range Method setValues() or Javascript Array splice method.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two arrays and you need to update empty elements of the old array with non-empty elements of the new array it can be done this way:

```js
var old_data = ['a', 'b', '', 'd', '',  ''];
var new_data = ['x', '',  'c', '', 'e', ''];

var updated_data = [];
for (var i in old_data) {
    if (old_data[i] != '') {
        updated_data.push(old_data[i]);
    } 
    else { 
        updated_data.push(new_data[i]);
    }
}

console.log(updated_data2); // [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', '' ]
```

Or:

```js
var old_data = ['a', 'b', '', 'd', '',  ''];
var new_data = ['x', '',  'c', '', 'e', ''];

var updated_data = old_data.map((old, i) => old || new_data[i]);

console.log(updated_data);  // [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', '' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

You can do the following:

- Retrieve the source dates and the target dates using [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues).
- From the source dates array, filter out the ones that are already present in target. You can use a combination of [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for that.
- Insert as much columns as element in the filtered array before the first column in the target sheet, using [insertColumnsBefore](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertColumnsBefore(Integer,Integer)).
- Call [flush](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) to make sure the script takes into account the inserted columns.
- Write the new dates using [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).

#### Code snippet:

```
const sourceId = "SOURCE_SPREADSHEET_ID";
const targetId = "TARGET_SPREADSHEET_ID";
const sourceSheetName = "Summary";
const targetSheetName = "Sum";

function copyDates() {
  const sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceId).getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);
  const sourceDates = sourceSheet.getRange("C:C").getValues().flat().filter(String);
  const targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetId).getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
  const currentDates = targetSheet.getRange("1:1").getValues()[0].filter(String);
  const newDates = sourceDates.filter(sourceDate => !currentDates.some(currentDate => currentDate.getTime() === sourceDate.getTime()));
  targetSheet.insertColumnsBefore(1, newDates.length);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  targetSheet.getRange(1,1,1,newDates.length).setValues([newDates]);
}
```

#### Important note:

The code snippet above will only work if all source and target dates are really [Dates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and not strings. If they were strings, you should not use [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) when comparing them in `some` (that's only used to compare `Dates`):

```
const newDates = sourceDates.filter(sourceDate => !currentDates.some(currentDate => currentDate === sourceDate));
```

Also, if you have some strings and some dates, but they are all formatted in the same way in the spreadsheet, you could use [getDisplayValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) instead of `getValues` to force them all to be strings. In this case you wouldn't use `getTime()` either. For example:

```
const sourceDates = sourceSheet.getRange("C:C").getDisplayValues().flat().filter(String);
// ...
const currentDates = targetSheet.getRange("1:1").getDisplayValues()[0].filter(String);
// ...
const newDates = sourceDates.filter(sourceDate => !currentDates.some(currentDate => currentDate === sourceDate));
```